# SQLite select value from tbl2 (or tlb1 if not exists)

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables `tbl1` and `tbl2` both with the rows `id` and `price` where `tbl1` contains many records and `tbl2` only a few

I want to select all entries from `tbl1` but want to replace `price` with the data from `tbl2` if it exists in `tbl2`

So far I got this query which does not work:

```
SELECT p.id,
       CASE p.id WHEN p.id IN (
                SELECT id
                  FROM tbl2
            )
       THEN o.price
       ELSE p.price END AS 'price'
  FROM tbl1 p
       LEFT JOIN tbl2 o ON p.id = o.id
```

Sample `tbl1`

```
id  price
1   1.23
2   4.56
3   7.89
```

Sample `tbl2`

```
id  price
2   99.99
```

Expected query result

```
id  price
1   1.23
2   99.99    <--- entry from tbl2
3   7.89
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `COALESCE` to select the correct price:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    COALESCE(o.price, p.price) price
FROM tbl1 p
LEFT JOIN tbl2 o
    ON p.id = o.id;
```

[image]

### Demo

The logic here is that we use the `price` from the second table, assuming it is present for a given `id`.  If it is *not* present, then we fall back to using the `price` from the first table.

Comment: This is brilliant Tim! Thank you so much - works like a charm. I'll accept your answer as soon as the minimum of 10 minutes passed